# PushFrame locks up WPF window when user is moving window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm using PushFrame to ensure that my window finishes drawing before executing additional code.  My application has some time sensitive functions that require the windows have been updated before I continues executing code.

So I'm using the sample from msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.pushframe(v=vs.110).aspx

Which works great, except, if a user is dragging my window when this code executes the window hangs and you can only get it back with a ctrl-alt-del.

Any ideas?

Comment: sounds really awkward. Why don't you just `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` with the proper `DispatcherPriority`?

Comment: That is the ONLY way to guarantee that you've actually painted to the screen before you return. You do know begin invoke is asyncronous?  If anything I'd want Invoke, but even with that you're still abstracted from the actual paint updates that the dispatcher handles in it's own time.

Comment: not really. using `DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle` guarantees that your code will be called after everything else has completed. BTW the word "painted" sounds too winforms. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Synchronize screen updates with physical hardware monitoring devices.

Comment: sounds to me you'd rather use the TPL and `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`

Comment: No that just marshalls to the foreground thread. I need to actually update what's on the screen.

Answer (score 6):

The application seems freezed because mouse capture is not automatically released from the window resize or `DragMove()` operation after the `Dispatcher.PushFrame()` is called from the user code.

The workaround would be to manually release mouse capture from any window in the application that is capturing the mouse prior to calling `Dispatcher.PushFrame()`:

```
        ...
        if (priority < DispatcherPriority.Loaded)
        {
            IntPtr capturingHandle = GetCapture();
            for (int i = 0; i < Application.Current.Windows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (new WindowInteropHelper(
                                            Application.Current.Windows[i]
                                           ).Handle == capturingHandle)
                {
                    Mouse.Capture(
                                  Application.Current.Windows[i],
                                  CaptureMode.Element
                                 );
                    Application.Current.Windows[i].ReleaseMouseCapture();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        ...
```

This workaround utilizes the `GetCapture()` p/invoke declaration:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetCapture();
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I do not have a solution for you but can only confirm we can reproduce this too in our application (and in a 50 line example program).
Feel free to vote [for this connect issue.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807292/wpf-application-intermittently-hangs-when-using-dispatcher-invoke-and-or-dispatcher-pushframe-while-user-is-resizing-or-draging-window)